# Azure Kubernetes GitOps flux

Tags: azure-aks, gitops, fluxcd

I hope someone can help with this issue.

I have an azure kubernetes service and i enabled GitOps linking the AKS to my github repository.

The connection succeded, and as testing purpose i wanted to install prometheus to have an understanding of flux and logic before to extend its use.

As a starting point i read the documentations and went for a github example how to deploy prometheus, the github project i called `flux2-monitoring-example`.

i downloaded the monitoring folder and pushed it to my repository that is linked to my aks gitops. But i get the following error:

```
"message": "HelmRelease/monitoring/loki-stack dry-run failed: failed to get API group resources: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta2: the server could not find the requested resource\n",
        "reason": "ReconciliationFailed",
        "status": "False",
        "type": "Ready"
    }
```

Before to try this example i tried to deploy different Helms repositories and the error is always the same. Did i miss something in the configurations or setup? i am really confused at this point.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide

Comment: if this is the message with every helmrelease, most likely the issue is on the flux side. it might not be configured correctly.

please check if you have flux-system resources running. (controllers)

Not sure but maybe my reference repository can help you in some way.

https://github.com/ishuar/kubernetes-in-real-life/tree/main/azure-kubernetes-service/gitops/fluxcd/observability/kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: i just confirmed that the configuratio is correct. I believe that the issue is regarding the specific version of fluxcd i am using as i am not really confident on how to find which version to use for each chart or kind

Comment: @ishuar i tried also this official documentation from flux. exactly the same repo, and still the same error https://fluxcd.io/flux/monitoring/metrics/